# How to input 0xA (\n) with Bash in Mac OS X 10.7.4

Tags: macos, bash

To input 0xD (\r), we have ^V^M (Ctrl+V, Ctrl+M).

When I input ^V^J (Ctrl+V, Ctrl+J) in the terminal, the cursor just jump to the beginning of a new line.

^V^J (Ctrl+V, Ctrl+J) works well in the AIX, ksh.

Actually, the problem is:

In a text file "foo.txt", the content is

```
aaa
bbb
```

In hex view: `61 61 61 0D 62 62 62`

I just like to use **sed 's/^M/^J/g' foo.txt** to replace `OD` to `OA`.

But the result is `sed 's/^M/`

```
/g' foo.txt`
```

in separated line.

Comment: Sounds like a Terminal bug to me.

Comment: It does the same thing in PuTTY in Windows connected to a Linux Box.

Answer (score 2):

`$'...'` interprets escape codes within, so you could use `$'\n'` to add a \n to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be mainly with how the input is echoed to screen. If I type `echo -n '`, Control-V, Control-J, `' | hexdump -C`, it shows that I've typed a newline character.

If I leave out the Control-V, the output is identical although bash shows a `>` prompt.  In this case, bash has seen the newline as it was typed and prompting for continuation since the quote was unterminated.  If I don't use Control-V and I just hit Return instead of Control-J, the result is identical to just hitting Control-J.

With Control-V but not the quotes, the Control-J is interpreted as a newline, but bash doesn't see it immediately.  So, typing `echo foo`, Control-V, Control-J, `echo bar` is equivalent to typing:

```
echo foo
echo bar
```

It issues two `echo` commands and prints:

```
foo
bar
```

The two lines (as seen by bash or readline) are both in the history, separately.

Think about it this way, what would you expect to happen if you issued the following command?

```
printf "echo foo\necho bar" | sh
```

(Note that `printf` interprets escape sequences in its input.)  Bash would interpret the newline in its input stream as a separator between two separate lines.  Well, when you type Control-V, Control-J, it's seeing the same thing and interprets it the same way.